# Подмена надписи

Tags: python, tkinter, snmp

Имеется скрипт, для снятия показаний на приборе.

```
from pysnmp.entity.rfc3413.oneliner import cmdgen
import tkinter as tk
def get_data_from_sensor(ip):
    cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()
    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, \
    varBindTable = cmdgen.CommandGenerator().bulkCmd(
        cmdgen.CommunityData('test-agent', 'public'),
        cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget((ip, 161)),
        0,
        25,
                ('1.3.6.1.4.1.41927.2.15.1.5'),  # IP
        ('1.3.6.1.4.1.41927.2.15.2.6'),  # Температура
        ('1.3.6.1.4.1.41927.2.15.2.7'),  # Вольтаж
        ('1.3.6.1.4.1.41927.2.15.2.1'),  # Входящий оптический сигнал
        ('1.3.6.1.4.1.41927.2.15.1.4'),  # Время работы               
    )
    if errorIndication:
        return errorIndication
    else:
        if errorStatus:
            return'%s at %s' % (
                errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                errorIndex and varBindTable[-1][int(errorIndex) - 1] or '?'
            )
        else:
            data = []
            for varBindTableRow in varBindTable:
                for name, val in varBindTableRow:
                    data.append('%s = %s' % (name.prettyPrint(), val.prettyPrint()))
            return '\n'.join(data)
def on_click():
    ip = sv.get()
    text = get_data_from_sensor(ip)
    text_area.insert(1.0, text)
root = tk.Tk()
sv = tk.StringVar()
lbl = tk.Label(text='IP ОП FORO').pack()
entry = tk.Entry(textvariable=sv, width=60)
entry.pack()
btn = tk.Button(text='получить данные', command=on_click)
btn.pack()
text_area = tk.Text(width=60, height=5)
text_area.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы сообщения OID' а типа:

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.41927.2.15.2.6.0
```

не выводились, а вместо них были надписи показателей, с каких считывается. Возможно ли это как то замутить? Фото прилагаю. Спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Уточните, что конкретно должно выводиться вместо оидов?

Comment: Поверьте не стоит перегружать вопрос какими-то личными данными, кому интересно счетчики у Вас или что-то еще, сформулируйте задачу проще, **как из такой строки сделать такую**, и еще приложите свой код, тут все таки не фриланс биржа. С уважением!

Comment: Сейчас: SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.41927.2.15.2.6.0 = 31. Хотелось бы Температура = 31.

Comment: Есть же код сверху

Answer (score 0):

Получаем текст показателей (это есть у вас в функции `def on_click()`):

```
text = get_data_from_sensor(ip)
```

Делаем подмену:

```
strings_list = text.splitlines()  # текст в список, где строка=>элемент
values_list = []
for string in strings_list:
    # string.split('=') разбивает строку по знаку = на список из 2 элементов
    values_list.append(string.split('=')[1])  # в список values_list добавляем последний элемент из полученного списка, т.е. 31, 120 и т.д.
features_list = ['Температура', 'Вольтаж', 'Входящий оптический сигнал', 'Время работы']
text = ''
for i in range (0, len(features_list)):
    string = features_list[i]+' ='+values_list[i]
    text = text+string+'\n'
```

Для примера, если:

```
text = 'SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.41927.2.15.2.6.0 = 31\n' \
       'SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.41927.2.15.2.7.0 = 120\n' \
       'SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.41927.2.15.2.1.0 = -300\n' \
       'SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.41927.2.15.1.4.0 = 29951\n'
```

Тогда после подмены в переменной `text` будет:

```
Температура = 31
Вольтаж = 120
Входящий оптический сигнал = -300
Время работы = 29951
```

Затем этот текст можно вставить в поле `text_area`:

```
text_area.insert(1.0, text)
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, показания будут в таком случае одинаковые. А мне нужно ['Температура', 'Вольтаж', 'Входящий оптический сигнал', 'Время работы'] статичные надписи, а показания будут считываться с прибора каждый раз (и не факт, что они будут одинаковые, там более время работы устройства)) Или я вообще ничего не понял(

Comment: Нет, почему статичные? Это я вам пример обработки конкретного текста привел, который у вас на скриншоте в поле. А текст в этом поле появляется у вас после клика на кнопку из функции ```def on_click():``` Посмотрите, у вас там строка ```text = get_data_from_sensor(ip)``` При её выполнении вы получаете в переменную ```text``` текст. А дальше вы его можете обработать, как я написал в ответе. И потом передать в поле

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: Благодарю, а вот сейчас уже интереснее.